# Remove Workflow Manager scopes?

Tags: 2013, powershell, workflow-manager

Is there any way to remove additional scope that get's created when you create a connection to multiple SharePoint Farms from a Workflow Manager service server?

```
Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite https://farmb.corp.local 
-WorkflowHostUri https://wffarm.corp.local:12290 -ScopeName FarmB
```

I found and tried [Remove-WFScope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193255(v=azure.10).aspx) but the scopes remain even after. IIS-resets/server reboots make's no difference.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the remove powershell command with path of scope. you have to provide full path.

also run the below powershell to check all the available scope

```
param([parameter(mandatory=$true)][string]$Endpoint, [string]$Path = "/", [string]$Parent = "None")

[Reflection.Assembly]::Load("Microsoft.Workflow.Client, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35") | Out-Null
Write-Output ""

function WriteScopeInfo([string]$scopeUri, [string]$path, [string]$parent) {
    $scopePath = $scopeUri + $path
    $client = New-Object -TypeName "Microsoft.Workflow.Client.WorkflowManagementClient" -ArgumentList $scopePath
    $manager = $client.CurrentScope
    $scope = $manager.Get()

    Write-Output "Name: `t`t`t$($scope.DisplayName)"
    Write-Output "Path: `t`t`t$($scope.Path)"
    Write-Output "Status: `t`t$($scope.Status.ToString())"
    Write-Output "User Comments: `t$($scope.UserComments)"
    Write-Output "Parent: `t`t$parent"
    Write-Output "Children: `t`t$($scope.ChildScopeCount)"
    Write-Output ""

    if ($scope.ChildScopeCount -gt 0) {
        $manager.GetChildScopes() | % { WriteScopeInfo $scopeUri $_.Path $scope.Path }
    }
}

WriteScopeInfo $Endpoint $Path $Parent
```

https://lennytech.wordpress.com/2013/08/12/listing-all-scopes-in-a-workflow-manager-instance-using-powershell/

Comment: I already knew the name of my scopes so i used the remove-wfscope and yet they remains in the browsers, and are "recreated" after a while, as they still show up after a while running the script above.